# How do I fix this "Input past end of file" error?

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I must find all the Steps containing `PGM=FTP` then read all the lines until I find another step that does not has `PGM=FTP`. It could be anything except `FTP`. I need all the chunk of lines to be written in another column with the corresponding program name.

This is an example input:

```
//GPFCGI1  DD DSN=PHGP.GPFCGIM.CGI.PATH,DISP=SHR
//GPFPWO2  DD DSN=PHGP.GPFMKT2.MKT.ESDS,DISP=SHR
//GPFPWO4  DD DSN=PHGP.GPFMKT4.MKT.ESDS,DISP=SHR
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN    DD *
//STEP006  EXEC PGM=FTP
//FILE01   DD DSN=PHGP.GPFMKT2.MKT.ESDS,DISP=SHR
//FILE02   DD DSN=PHGP.GPFMKT4.MKT.ESDS,DISP=SHR
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN    DD *
OPEN HKGSPADD.AP.MANULIFE.COM                                    
NOLOG *****Dummy Member Include**********************************
ASCII                                                            
PUT  %FILE01,ESDS,FB,80,80   CXX_TRIAL4_ELIGIBLE_PAC_PAP.CSV     
PUT  %FILE02,ESDS,FB,86,86   CXX_TRIAL4_WORK_ELIGIBLE_PAC_PAP.DAT
BYE                                                              
//STEP007  EXEC PGM=IDCAMS
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN    DD *
 DELETE ( PHGP.GPFMKT1.MKT.INT.KSDS ) PURGE CLUSTER
DELETE ( PHGP.GPFMKT2.MKT.ESDS ) PURGE CLUSTER    
DELETE ( PHGP.GPFMKT3.MKT.KSDS ) PURGE CLUSTER    
DELETE ( PHGP.GPFMKT3.MKT.TXT.ESDS ) PURGE CLUSTER
DELETE ( PHGP.GPFMKT4.MKT.ESDS ) PURGE CLUSTER    
//*
```

I created this Sub, but it gives me a "Runtime error 62: Input past end of file". Why?

```
Sub Define()
    Dim file As Object
    Dim flag As String
    flag = True
    folder = "D:\DOWNLOADS\New folder"
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    J = 1
    'Opening the file in READ mode
    Set FLD = objFSO.GetFolder(folder)
    For Each file In FLD.Files
        Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(file)
        Do While Not objFile.AtEndOfStream
            If contents Like "*PGM=FTP" Then
                'If InStr(contents, "*PGM=FTP") Then
                flag = True
                contents3 = contents

                Do Until flag = False
                    strline = objFile.Readline
                    If strline Like "//STEP*" Then
                        flag = False
                        contents = strline
                    Else
                        contents3 = contents3 & vbNewLine & strline
                    End If
                Loop
                Sheets(1).Cells(J, 1).Value = file.Name
                Sheets(1).Cells(J, 2).Value = contents3
                J = J + 1
            Else
                contents = objFile.Readline
            End If

        Loop
    Next
    objFile.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: You're doing a Readline in the middle `strline = objFile.Readline` without checking for end of stream. Try putting a check there?

Comment: -1: please come up with better title than "URGENT assistance needed with VBA".

Comment: -@AlexeiLevenkov sorry about the title but I am kinda new here and I really need this..Hope you understand :)
Can you do something to it???

Comment: -@wwkudu
I have already done the checking Do While Not objFile.AtEndOfStream while opening the file but dont know how to put that check in between.Can you show me please?

Comment: For starters, put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, and explicitly `Dim` all of your variables.

Comment: @mehow: After a tiny bit of editing (especially the ridiculous title), this question is just fine...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett this is an ideal case of a [help-vampire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem) type of question. See comment below the answer

Answer (score 2):

You need a simple loop (just one .ReadLine per turn to avoid reading past EOF) and a variable keeping track of whether you have seen a FTP line. In code:

```
  Dim tsIn : Set tsIn = goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\in.txt")
  Dim bFtpSeen : bFtpSeen = False
  Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
     Dim sLine : sLine = tsIn.ReadLine()
     Select Case True
       Case 1 = Instr(sLine, "//STEP") And 12 = Instr(sLine, "EXEC PGM=FTP")
         bFtpSeen = True
         WScript.Echo "FTP", tsIn.Line - 1, sLine
       Case 1 = Instr(sLine, "//STEP") And 12 = Instr(sLine, "EXEC PGM=")
         If bFtpSeen Then
            bFtpSeen = False
            WScript.Echo "other after FTP", tsIn.Line - 1, sLine
         Else
         End If
       Case Else
    End Select
  Loop
  tsIn.Close
```

Comment: Can you please tell me in a simpler way as I am still exploring VBA.Let me know where shall I insert this snippet to make my code work.
Warm Regards,

Comment: wasted time helping a help vampire ;)

Comment: @mehow: I think an upvote is a better mark of appreciation than a ha-ha, told you so, type comment...